# Can I make elastic beanstalk route a request to ALL of the instances under it?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My service running in elastic beanstalk environment has a rest api. Periodically, I have another service that hits one of the rest endpoints to alert the service to do some work (computer vision in this case).

The load balancer sends that request to only one ec2 instance, so currently that instance does all the work while the others do nothing. I would like to distribute the work load over all the instances.

Can I tell my load balancer to route requests to that api to ALL the instances under it so that they all start working?

Comment: Wouldn't this just duplicate the work? How would the servers know how to share the workload?

Comment: You are correct. I ended up using amazon SQS and a worker environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out how to do this, but I realized that my initial approach wasn't very good. I ended up creating a worker environment, and feeding it tasks using amazon SQS.